# Получение данных во View через Ajax ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Не могу понять как перехватить данные во View ASP.NET с помощью AJAX
Есть вот такой метод он выводит во View Json данные.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult AjaxGetItems(FormCollection form) {
    return Json(RequestItems(int.Parse(form["select"]), form["sort"]));
}
```

Получается сплошной Json. Но проблема в чем все что я пишу во View ничего нет. Т.е не разметки. Не принудительный команд которые должны запуститься при запуске View. Даже для теста alert() прописал что бы если страница запуститься что бы показало что работает. Но получается что метод выводит как будто сторонне сгенерированную страницу. В обход той на которую он по умолчанию должен все кидать. Подскажите что я делаю не так. Ищу но в сети интернет много про Ajax много про asp но найти конкретное решение для моей проблемы очень сложно. Все в перемешку.

Answer (score 2):

Ваш метод `JSON` выводит не во `View` а прямо и возвращает клиенту, скажем так в обход `View`.

Что бы передать данные во `View` используется функция `return View();`

Кроме того во `View` нет необходимости передавать `Json`, в него можно передавать любые нативные C# объекты.

```
return View(myObject);
```

Ajax и Json используются по другому. Логика их работы такова что есть страница уже загруженная на клиент, и она без перезагрузки страницы через функцию `fetch` или аналогичную делает `post` или другой запрос, обычно такой запрос возвращает `Json` данные которые обрабатываются Javascript и результат обработки выводится на страницу, без перезагрузки.

Если вам нужно сделать страницу делающую Ajax запрос. То это должна быть отдельная от самого запроса страница, то есть обычная страница

```
public IActionResult MyAction1() {
   return View();
}
```

Внутри `View` которой есть код делающий и обрабатывающий `Ajax` запрос.

Полный синтаксис зависит от версии ASP.NET которую используете.

Answer (score 1):

Вы рассматриваете только одну страницу (которая отдаёт json), смотрите шире: есть ещё другая страница, которая обрабатывает этот json.

Например. У меня есть сущность MoneyTransfer (перевод денег), это некоторый класс, в котором фигурирует отправитель денег и получатель денег:

```
public class MoneyTransfer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public int SenderId { get; set; }

    public Contact Sender { get; set; }

    public int RecipientId { get; set; }

    public Contact Recipient { get; set; }

    public decimal Amount { get; set; }

    public string Notes { get; set; }
}
```

И у меня есть CRUD-контроллер, который выводит список переводов, может удалить, добавить или отредактировать перевод.

На этом контроллере есть action для добавления перевода:

```
[Authorize]
public class MoneyTransferController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(string returnUrl)
    {
        ...
        return this.View();
    }
```

И именно в этом view запрашиваются JSON-данные (чуть позже я покажу этот view). Но запрашиваются они у совершенно другого контроллера и именно там происходит отдача JSON:

```
public class ContactController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SearchJson(ContactSearchViewModel model)
    {
        var contacts = await this.ContactService.SearchAsync(model.Needle, this.CurrentUserId);
        return this.Json(contacts);
    }
```

Вот этот вот второй контроллер - это то, что вы написали в своем вопросе. Но за кадром у вас осталась страница-приёмник JSON:

```
@model CreateMoneyTransferViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Создать перевод денег";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
        <form asp-route-returnurl="@Model.ReturnUrl" method="post">
            <input asp-for="SenderId" type="hidden" />
            <input asp-for="RecipientId" type="hidden" />
            <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Date"></label>
                <input asp-for="Date" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Date" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="SenderDisplayName"></label>
                <input asp-for="SenderDisplayName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="SenderDisplayName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="RecipientDisplayName"></label>
                <input asp-for="RecipientDisplayName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="RecipientDisplayName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Amount"></label>
                <input asp-for="Amount" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Amount" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Notes"></label>
                <textarea asp-for="Notes" class="form-control" rows="10" data-val-maxlength-max="900"></textarea>
                <span asp-validation-for="Notes" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Сохранить</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.IAntiforgery Xsrf
@functions{
    private string GetAntiXsrfRequestToken()
    {
        return Xsrf.GetAndStoreTokens(Context).RequestToken;
    }
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
        <form method="post">
            <input type="hidden" id="SearchContactRequestVerificationToken" name="RequestVerificationToken" value="@GetAntiXsrfRequestToken()">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Needle">Поиск контакта:</label>
                <input id="Needle" name="Needle" class="form-control" onkeyup="search_contact_for_moneytransfer(this.value);" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
        <div id="results"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
    div#results pre {
        margin-top: 10px;
    }

    div#results .btn {
        margin-right: 10px;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function search_contact_for_moneytransfer(needle) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "@Url.Action("SearchJson", "Contact", new {Area="Office"})",
            headers:
            {
                "RequestVerificationToken": $("#SearchContactRequestVerificationToken").val()
            },
            data: {
                "Needle": needle
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $('#results').html("");
                $(data).each(function(index, item) {
                    var ancor = $('<a>', { href: '/Office/Contact/Summary/' + item.id, text: item.displayName, "class": 'btn btn-default' });
                    var buttonSender = $('<button>',
                        {
                            click: function() {
                                chooseSender(item.id, item.displayName);
                             },
                             "class": "btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-plus",
                            text: "отправитель"
                        });
                    var buttonRecipient = $('<button>',
                        {
                            click: function() {
                                chooseRecipient(item.id, item.displayName);
                             },
                             "class": "btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-plus",
                            text: "получатель"
                        });
                    var pre = document.createElement("pre");
                    pre.textContent = item.notes;
                    $('#results').append(
                            $(document.createElement('div')).append(ancor).append(buttonSender).append(buttonRecipient).append(pre)
                    );
                });
            }
        });
    }
    function chooseSender(id, title) {
        $("#SenderId").val(id);
        $("#SenderDisplayName").val(title);
    }
    function chooseRecipient(id, title) {
        $("#RecipientId").val(id);
        $("#RecipientDisplayName").val(title);
    }
</script>
@section Scripts {
    @await Html.PartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial")
}
```

Посмотрите, из каких частей состоит эта страница.

Во-первых, есть сама форма.

Во-вторых, есть javascript, который собственно отправляет POST-запрос.

В-третьих, есть javascript, который преобразует полученный JSON в HTML-разметку.