# ASP.NET. JS. Как отправить модель с клиента на сервер?

Tags: c#, asp.net

`Owner` модель:

```
[DataType("ForeignKey")]
[ForeignKey("User")]
public int UserId { get; set; }

[DataType("Reference")]
public User Users { get; set; }

[DataType("ForeignKey")]
[ForeignKey("Type")]
public int TypeId { get; set; }

[DataType("Reference")]
public Type Types { get; set; }
```

Формирую объект на js:

```
var modelTitle = "пример";
var user = {
    UserId: 2,
    TypeId: 3
};
```

Делаю POST

```
$.post("@Url.Action("Create", "Home")",
{
    title: modelTitle,
    model: JSON.stringify(user)
});
```

Принимаю в контроллере:

```
public void Create(string title, Owner model)
{

}
```

Мб я модель собираю как то не так, ибо `title` приходит, а на моделе - `null`, хотя я думал что ему достаточно того, что свойства внутри него идентичны.

Мб я что то не учел?

Comment: А смысл вам отвечать, если вы не доводите свои темы до конца? Вам пишут комментарии и ответы, вы почти не реагируете.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov эти два вопроса по сути взаимосвязаны(прошлый про ID). У меня появился вариант того как это можно исправить, но для начала я застял тут.

Comment: [Проблема XY](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/213987) detected и вы всё дальше от исходного вопроса и всё более костылясто двигаетесь к забиванию гвоздей микроскопом.

Comment: @AK просто работаю с заброшенным github проектом и переписываю на основе своего прошлого говнокода. Решил не вставлять, ибо чем больше о нем будет известно - тем больше вопросов будет всплывать. 

Я просто учусь.

Comment: Создайте другое приложение с нуля. Я за день десяток скетчей пишу, чтобы опробовать те или иные моменты. И даже просто пример приложения [выложил](https://github.com/akmetainfo/WallyBackend) на github, а также в вопросах/пишу на фейковых классах типа [Order + OrderPosition](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/863076/213987).

Comment: Возможно вы не учли Antiforgery токен? пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/809366/213987 Не уверен, что в core это нужно, сам давно не делал - ушёл на vue.js запросы.

Comment: @AK потратил суммарно больше 300 часов, банально хочется труп допинать по хоть какого то вида..

Comment: @AK токен не помог, но я увидел там ViewModel и создал такой же вместо модели и только с ID полями. Мне помогло.

Comment: Ну что, хоть так-то помогает... Но на будущее: чтобы не сидеть по 300 часов и в раздражении наобум ставить костыли -- лучше проинвестировать часть из этого в целенаправленное обучение и идти чётко к цели.